# Entity Framework Reverse Engineering Code First: missing the foreign key relationships in the generated code

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I try to use EF Reverse Engineer Code First to generate code from a Database,
However, the auto-generated code missed some foreign key relations.
What could be the reason?

Comment: Can you give s specific example, there could be a different reason for each one.

Comment: @BenRobinson, what other info do you need?

Comment: An example of a database table definition and the associated class generated by the EF reverse engineer tool.

Comment: @BenRobinson, I think i've just figured out. The column in the primary key table is not a primary key but only a unique constraint. EF does not recognize the unique constraint. could this be the reason?

Comment: Yes, EF does not support unique constraints.

Answer (score 3):

This is a bug in the designer, that I fixed here https://entityframework.codeplex.com/workitem/667 
You can download the EF Tools version 6.1.2 or later, which contains the fix. See blogpost on the ADO.NET blog for download links