# Entity Framework "Database First" not generating Foreign keys

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework-6, visual-studio-2015

I used entity framework reverse engineering but it seems to miss some foreign key relations.
Here are my database sql code and the generated classes:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[rapportAnomalie] (
[code_rapport] INT          IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
[date_rapport] DATETIME     NOT NULL,
[etat]         VARCHAR (50) NOT NULL,
[code_agence]  INT          NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([code_rapport] ASC),
CONSTRAINT [FK_rapportAnomalie_ToTable] FOREIGN KEY ([code_agence]) REFERENCES [dbo].[agence] ([code_agence])


CREATE TABLE agence
(
[code_agence] INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, 
[intitule_agence] VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL, 
[adresse_agence] VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL
)
```

Agence.cs:

```
[Table("agence")]
public partial class agence
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
    public int code_agence { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(100)]
    public string intitule_agence { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(100)]
    public string adresse_agence { get; set; }
 }
}
```

and Rapport.cs:

```
[Table("rapportAnomalie")]
public partial class rapportAnomalie
{
    [Key]
    public int code_rapport { get; set; }

    public DateTime date_rapport { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(50)]
    public string etat { get; set; }

    public int code_agence { get; set; }
}
}
```

what could be the problem there?

Comment: What is the version of EF you are working with?

Comment: entity framework 6.1.3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just ended up editing it manually adding the forgein key annotation:

```
[Table("rapportAnomalie")]
public partial class rapportAnomalie
 {
    [Key]
    public int code_rapport { get; set; }

    public DateTime date_rapport { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(50)]
    public string etat { get; set; }

    public int code_agence { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("code_agence")]
    public agence agence { get; set; }
 }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Probably a duplicate question with the following link[The question posed on stack over flow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26777448/entity-framework-reverse-engineering-code-first-missing-the-foreign-key-relatio)

And here the related answer of the above link which I guess could be of value for you[EF Reveres Engineering](https://entityframework.codeplex.com/workitem/667)

Good luck